# Glassfish 3.1: spring error during deploy of web application

Tags: spring, deployment, glassfish-3

Strange thing: when I deploy the web application into GF 3.1 through the **autodeploy** directory, I recieve the following error. The deployment through the admin console **works ok** with the same war!

here is the exception:

> [#|2011-03-19T20:36:06.836+0000|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=51;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Adding
>   singleton for WebappClassLoader
>   (delegate=false;
>   repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)|#]
>
> [#|2011-03-19T20:36:14.876+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|ContainerBase.addChild:
>   start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException:
>   **Error creating managed object for
>   class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener**
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5271)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:500)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:755)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1980)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1630)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:100)
>           at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
>           at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
>           at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:286)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
>           at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:360)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
>           at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoOperation.run(AutoOperation.java:145)
>           at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deploy(AutoDeployer.java:577)
>           at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deployAll(AutoDeployer.java:463)
>           at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:395)
>           at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:380)
>           at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployService$1.run(AutoDeployService.java:213)
>           at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
>           at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
>   Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException:
>   Error creating managed object for
>   class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:2688)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addApplicationListener(StandardContext.java:1932)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureApplicationListener(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:234)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureWebModule(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:93)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModuleContextConfig.start(WebModuleContextConfig.java:274)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModuleContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(WebModuleContextConfig.java:172)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:149)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5268)
>           ... 26 more Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException:
>   Error creating managed object for
>   class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.createListener(StandardContext.java:2798)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadListener(StandardContext.java:4745)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.loadListener(WebModule.java:1603)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:2685)
>           ... 33 more Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException:
>   Error creating managed object for
>   class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>           at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:317)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.createListenerInstance(WebContainer.java:734)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.createListenerInstance(WebModule.java:1981)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.createListener(StandardContext.java:2796)
>           ... 36 more **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException**
>           at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.managedbean.ManagedBeanManagerImpl.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanManagerImpl.java:485)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.managedbean.ManagedBeanManagerImpl.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanManagerImpl.java:428)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:300)
>           ... 39 more

NPE in the official release?? Isn't this the indicator of new bug in GF?

Piece of my web.xml:

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Using the latest (3.0.2.RELEASE) version of Spring-web

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug report is here :
http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16237

turned out to be mistake with Spring dependency.

I was hoping this had a real solution. Because I also got this problem and my app doesn't use Spring at all! Just Weld/CDI + EJB in GlassFish 3.1.

Comment: Thanks, Hendy, that was just my own jira task :)